# How to get SharePoint List from SQL server

Tags: sharepoint

My scenario is i have already created one webservices for my infopath form. I have published this form to the sharepoint library. When i insert data into browser enable form it will store in SQL server. Now i want to display this data into sharepoint list or library. please ny one can help me out. Thank you.

Comment: You might also want to ask/move this question to http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can use Data View Web Part to connect to an external source like SQL and display data with this web part. Simply create a web part page and user SharePoint designer to insert Data View web part. [This article](http://zavuga.blogspot.com/2009/07/dataview-webpart-sharepoint-designer.html) describes how to do it in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to real data integration (not just displaying) follow the steps given in this video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tdNO5y14LSc

It shows, how connect a real WSS 3.0 SharePoint 2007 / 2010 list (no web part, e.g. contact or task list) to almost any external data source, codeless, bi-diectional and in just 5 minutes with all list features available. For example you can start workflows in SharePoint, if external data changes, or you have RSS/E-Mail change notifications, you can add attachments or any other additional web 2.0 information like tags, comments...